# Can Customer community and Company Site integrated in one layer?

Tags: community, customer-community

I got to connect customer to our business through salesforce community features as part of sales cloud. Community then will be used by our customers to browse the product, pricing, placing order, chatter etc., Further my organization has its own website (not a salesforce domain) where customer usually login for product browsing , placing order etc.,

Now my Organization does not want to get rid of their own website by community instead they want to integrate company site with communities.

I am not very sure how this is achievable?

Appreciate your suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

What is the backend database for your company site ? You could integrate this database to salesforce community using the necessary api's . There are Other products which can achieve this ,

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/salesforce-community-integration.html